# How to download Launchpad ppa repositories on an android device to be installed on an airgapped ubuntu system

Tags: ubuntu

I have a completely air-gapped system. how can I download this(https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages) repository on my android device so i can run the install command for gdal-bin

```
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
```

need to do this because I am trying to run the command

```
gdalbuildvrt somegeotiff.vrt * .tif
```

but it says command not found, but can be installed with :

```
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
```

to finish a vts-geospatial project.